# Assign to several cells using Excel If-Else Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

A number of students are divided into groups for a project. The projects are marked and the group scores are assigned to each student in that group. A sample Excel sheet is attached. [image]

The equation for the Score (column C) is given as: `=IF(B2="A",F2,IF(B2="B",F3,IF(B2="C",F4,"Error")))`

However, the Excel sheet is not working the way I want. In the example, Sarah should get 80, the same as Michael, since they both belong to Group A. John should have 78 and not 0 since he belongs to Group B and so on.

The reason this is happening is that column F (the Group scores) keeps getting auto-incremented by Excel in the function. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula should written like this:

```
=IF(B2="A",$F$2,IF(B2="B",$F$3,IF(B2="C",$F$4,"Error")))
```

Or to make it dynamic formula should be like this:

```
=IF(B2=$E$2,$F$2,IF(B2=$E$3,$F$3,IF(B2=$E$4,$F$4,"Error")))
```

Check the Screen Shot:

[image]

Comment: Happy to hear from you & Glad to help you,,, keep asking please :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use $ to make your references absolute (and thus not auto-increment).  I would also suggest using vlookup or match/index combination to simplify.

Score for Michael would be

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$E$2:$F$4,2)
```

Fill down for Sarah and hers will update automagically to

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$E$2:$F$4,2)
```